# Desktop application database for python program

Tags: python, database, sqlite, desktop-application, embedded-database

I am designing a desktop application using Python.
I am facing a problem in choosing the most appropriate database, the program works online and offline.
In the case of offline, there is no problem because I find SQLite very suitable, but the problem is when the program works online, in this case I need to put the database on the cloud so that it is easy to deal with and access it from anywhere.
My question here is what is the best solution to this problem? Is there a database that can be embedded with the program for local use and at the same time it can be used as a server on the cloud?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can say that You can use  PouchDB as client side Work and for data sync on user side any database suitable which is use CouchDB sync protocol.

I also worked with postgreSQL and kinto.js but it's not as user friendly as PochDB.

Comment: Looks very promising I will look at it Thank you!